# How to connect circle from one svg file to another svg file on same html page in d3 using any layout

Tags: d3.js

I have two div on html page having id container1 and container2 i have created svg for each div and each svg contain circle, Now i want to connect two circle

Is it possible to connect two circle from two svg file on same page (cx,cy of both circle should genrate automatically)

My code snnipet..

Html

```
<div id="container1 " style="width:900px;height:800px;border:solid;"></div>
<div id="container2 " style="width:900px;height:100px;border:solid; margin-top: 25px;"></div>

created svg for container1 ,container2  using below code
  var svg = d3.select("#"+id).append("svg")
                           .attr("width", $("#"+id).css("width"))
                           .attr("height",$("#"+id).css("height"));
```

and draw circle for each container using force layout

Now I want to connect these two circle using line
How is it possible ???

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps adding a picture of what you want would help. However, Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Please show what you have already tried to solve the problem and explain why it is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For your general question "how is it possible?", here is a general approach to get you started:

1. Super-impose a third, mostly transparent SVG over the whole page using absolute positioning.  Draw the line inside this SVG.
2. Use [`.getScreenCTM()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getScreenCTM) (get screen cumulative transformation matrix) to calculate the position of each circle on the page.
3. Use the same function to figure out the transformation from the screen to your overlay SVG, and multiply one screen CTM by the inverse of the other to get the net transformation so you can figure the start and end coordinates of your lines from the coordinates of your circles.
4. Add a listener to the web page as a whole for any re-layout events, and re-do the calculations above as necessary.

If all of that sounds too confusing, you might want to come up with an alternate web page design that puts all the graphics in one SVG.  Or one which allows for a different way to indicate that elements are connected (same colour, or hover over one causes highlight on the other).

P.S.  You *might* be able to use [`.getTransformToElement()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getTransformToElement) to replace steps 2 and 3, but you'll want to test that out thoroughly.  I've never tried using it to find the transformation between elements in different SVGs on the same web page.